# Copy table from one system to a h2 in memory DB through while loop not working

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, h2

I'm trying to pull data from an onsite location into an in-memory h2 database, the below code pulls from the 'MLB.' table and results can be printed, however this then seems to skip the while loop and prints the 'completed' line. My connections definitely work, I've performed tests on the below code and I can write and select from the h2 table, as well as the db2 table outside of the loop.

Guidance on how to make the below work, pulling data from the MLB.SC_EP table into the in memory h2 table will be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void queryh2() throws SQLException {

    Connection connection2 = getDBConnection();
    Connection connection1 = getDZConnection();
    Statement st1 = connection1.createStatement();
    Statement createstmt = null;
    PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
    createstmt = connection2.createStatement();
    createstmt.execute("CREATE TABLE testtable(CLIENTCOUNTRY varchar(255), CLIENTNAME varchar(255))");

    st1.setFetchSize(10000);
    ResultSet rs = st1.executeQuery("Select CLIENTCOUNTRY, CLIENTNAME from MLB.SC_EP");

    while(rs.next())
    {   
        // int res;
        final String COUNTRY = rs.getString("CLIENTCOUNTRY");
        final String OPPDESC = rs.getString("CLIENTNAME");

        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        ps = connection2.prepareStatement("insert into testtable values(?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, COUNTRY);
        ps.setString(2, OPPDESC);
        ps.setFetchSize(10000);

        ps.executeUpdate();


        ResultSet rs1 = createstmt.executeQuery("select * from testtable");
        System.out.println(rs1.getInt("CLIENTCOUNTRY"));
   }
   System.out.println("completed");    
}
```

Comment: Your question suggests the result-set is empty, but the same query returns data 'outside the loop' -what does that mean?.    Compare the result if you don't use setFetchSize and instead append ' fetch first 10000 rows only ' to your SELECT query,  and also perform the prepareStatement only once outside the while-loop. You could use the Db2 command-line (if you have a Db2 client installed and can connect to Db2)  to export the Db2 table content to CSV file and then use H2 to import that CSV file. That seems less code. Which Db2 jdbc driver-version are you using?

Comment: @mao `setFetchSize(10000)` doesn't do the same thing as `fetch first 10000 rows only`. The first retrieves rows in blocks of 10000, and the second only returns the first 10000 rows.

Comment: If your code would enter the while-loop, then it would fail at the first iteration, as you're calling `rs1.getInt` before moving to the first row (and even checking there is a first row). However, you should provide a [mcve], I don't see anything that would obviously explain your problem (although your code is leaking resources, and has other issues).